# Demonstrate that the plane can not be covered countable copy of the letter $Y$

Tags: general-topology

Demonstrate that the plane ($\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$) can not be covered countable copy of the letter $Y$.

I have no idea how to do it. I'll be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: You might add what have you tried.

Comment: Well, that only works if $Y$ is considered a union of three line segments (If $Y$ had an interior, it would contain a Ball of size $\epsilon$ and then you can put the $Y$ on rational coordinates and you're done).

Comment: If Y is supposed to be lines, then it is nowhere dense. Apply Baire.

Comment: OK, so with Baire theory if I have a countable boundary sets there is impossible to cover a plane with interior? I am not sure if I correct understand the cover theory.

Comment: still don't get it

Comment: A 1-dimensional $Y$ (three segments, area zero) or a 2-dimensional $Y$ (area>0).

Answer (score 3):

The union of countably many letters $Y$ has  measure zero, so cannot be $\mathbb R^2$.
The same results holds for the 25 other letters and for that matter for any letter in the Cyrillic, Hebrew or Klingon alphabet.

Comment: But how to show it without measure theory?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(g_k)_{k\geq1}$ be the set of lines occurring in all these Y's, let $U_n:=\bigcup_{1\leq k\leq n} g_k$ be the union of the first $n$ of these lines, and let $U$ be the union of all of them. We shall construct a point $\xi\in{\mathbb R}^2\setminus U$ as follows:

Let $B_0$ be the closed unit disk, and suppose that for some $n\geq0$ a compact disk $B_n$ of  radius $3^{-n}>0$ has been choosen such that $B_n\cap U_n=\emptyset$. The line $g_{n+1}$ may intersect $B_n$, but it is possible to find a closed disk $B_{n+1}\subset B_n$ of radius $3^{-(n+1)}$ that does not meet $g_{n+1}$. It follows that $B_{n+1}\cap U_{n+1}=\emptyset$.

There is a point $\xi\in\bigcap_{n\geq0} B_n$, and it is easy to verify that $\xi\not\in U$.